# Proving a set Sigma Algebra 2

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D$ be a collection of subsets of a set $X$ with the following properties:

1. $X \in D$
2. $A, B \in D$ then $A\setminus B \in D$

Show that $D$ is an Algebra of subsets of $X$

So,

$X \in D$ by definition.

Let $G \in D$. Then $G^c = X\setminus G \in D$ since $X,G \in D$

The last part is where I'm stuck!

Not sure how to show that $G_1,G_2,G_3,\dots, G_n \in D$ then union of $G1,\dots,Gn \in D$

Comment: I believe that you trying to prove the impossible, $D$ is algebra, and **not** $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Correct! I meant as a finite union!

Comment: I believe also that you need another property, i.e.: for all $A,B\in D$ also $A\cup B\in D$ **or** for all $A,B\in D$ also $A\cap B\in D$

Comment: This problem is strictly from the text ( J Yeh Real Analysis problem 1.6). If I assume the last property then the proof follows smoothly. However, I don't think this is the intention of the problem.